# Replacing elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem thats giving me a huge ache. 
This piece of code purpose is to fill up an array with integer values and at the same time defend against strings and etc....but it doesn't defend against duplicates, but tried I got to far as replacing the number with a new number for example 
Enter 6 integers
1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5

my code will let me replace that 2 at position 1 with another number. What I want it to do is not to repeat the same number again, for example please replace 2 at position 1. I dont want the user to enter 2 again... and I want to make it to double check the work the array if any repeating numbers exists thank you.

```
        system("clear");
        printf("\nEntering Winning Tickets....\n");
        nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{1, 0}}, NULL);

        system("clear");
        char userInput[256];
        char c;

        int duplicationArray[6] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            printf("\nPlease enter the %d winning ticket number!(#'s must be between 1-49): ", i+1);
            fgets(userInput, 256, stdin);
            if ((sscanf(userInput, "%d %c", &winningNumbers[i], &c) != 1 || (winningNumbers[i] <= 0) || winningNumbers[i] >= 50))
            {
                printf("\nInvalid Input.\n") ;
                nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0, 350000000}}, NULL);
                system("clear");
                i = i - 1;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 6 - 1; ++i)
        {

            min = i;
            for (j = i+1; j < 6; ++j)
            {
                if (winningNumbers[j] < winningNumbers[min])
                    min = j;
            }

            temp = winningNumbers[i];
            winningNumbers[i] = winningNumbers[min];
            winningNumbers[min] = temp;

        }

        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if (winningNumbers[i] == winningNumbers[i+1])
            {
                duplicationArray[i] = i;
                duplicationCounter++;

            }

            else
            {
                duplicationCounter--;
            }
        }


           if (duplicationCounter > -6)

        {

            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                int j, min, temp;
                min = i;
                for (j = i+1; j < 6; ++j)
                {
                    if (duplicationArray[j] > duplicationArray[min])
                        min = j;
                }

                temp = duplicationArray[i];
                duplicationArray[i] = duplicationArray[min];
                duplicationArray[min] = temp;

            }

            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (duplicationArray[i] == -1)
                {
                    zeroCounter++;
                }
            }
            int resize = (6 - zeroCounter)+1;

            for (i = 0; i <= resize; i++)
            {
                if (duplicationArray[i] == -1)
                {
                    i++;
                }

                else if (duplicationArray[i] != -1)
                {
                    system("clear");

                    printf("\nDuplicated numbers has been dected in your array. ");
                    printf("\nPlease replace the number %d at postion %d with another number: ", winningNumbers[duplicationArray[i]], duplicationArray[i]);
                    fgets(userInput, 256, stdin);

                    if ((sscanf(userInput, "%d %c", &winningNumbers[duplicationArray[i]], &c) != 1 || (winningNumbers[i] <= 0) || winningNumbers[i] >= 50))
                    {
                        printf("\nInvalid Input.\n") ;
                        nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0, 350000000}}, NULL);
                        system("clear");
                        i = i - 1;
                    }
                }               
            }

            duplicationCounter = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (winningNumbers[i] == winningNumbers[i+1])
                {
                    duplicationArray[i] = i;
                    duplicationCounter++;

                }

                else
                {
                    duplicationCounter--;
                }

            }

            printf("%d, ", duplicationCounter);

        }
```

Comment: You should add comment lines to describe what each block is supposed to do.

Comment: use 50bit for duplicate check.

Comment: @user694733 Sorry I kinda described it in the beginning

Comment: @BLUEPIXY whats that?

Comment: input number range (1-50) {x | 1 <= x <= 50},
It can be seen immediately duplicate values ​​if I set the bit corresponding to the time you enter a numerical value whether it has been entered.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I still don't get it sorry. Is it a algorithm, a function??

Comment: @Leoc he means a lookup table of flags, indexed by your input values, initially set to all-0's. As you scan the string, use each value to set the flag in the array if it isn't already set. If it is, then that is your first duplicate, and hence the set is not valid.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah that's beyond my understandings of C!

Comment: Not really, it isn't at all. If you can get/set values in an array, you can do this.

Comment: There is a need to re-sort to be the assumption that duplicate detection of then are sorted after replaced with the new input duplicate values ​​in your code.
In addition, there is a problem with the creation and use of `duplicationArray`.

Comment: Whats the problem with it?

Comment: ex)duplicationArray no set -1 -> resize too bigger and always change.

Comment: and `&winningNumbers[duplicationArray[i]]` already `i` is changed!.

Comment: The purpose of the duplicationArray was to store the locations of where there were duplications. The reason why I set it to -1 so I can see the difference, because you can have a dupe number at element 0. I don't get what you are proposing to me :(

Comment: `for (i = duplicationArray[i]; i <= resize; i++)` ... `if ((sscanf(userInput, "%d %c", &winningNumbers[duplicationArray[i]]...` Please consider a particular index within the meaning of this.

Comment: I recently changed for (i = duplicationArray[i] to 0)

Comment: if ((sscanf(userInput, "%d %c", &winningNumbers[duplicationArray[i]]
This line helps me to replace the dupe number at the location, and replace it with a new at the same time

if I had a dupe number at element 0 it will access the number in the winningNUmbers that is duped

Comment: `I recently changed for (i = duplicationArray[i] to 0) ` I do not get to know it.

Comment: With all do with respect I really don't get what you are trying to say to me

Comment: A say in the code that are being presented to me, I will be known that it has been corrected for part modification does not appear?

Comment: I have re-edit it for you. It should be there

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define DATA_SIZE 6

int main(void){
    char userInput[256];
    int inputNum, winningNumbers[DATA_SIZE];
    uint64_t table = 0;
    int i=0;
    while(i<DATA_SIZE){
        printf("\nPlease enter the %d winning ticket number!(#'s must be between 1-49): ", i+1);
        fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);
        if(sscanf(userInput, "%d", &inputNum) != 1 || inputNum <= 0 || inputNum >= 50)
            continue;
        uint64_t bit = 1 << inputNum;
        if(table & bit)
            continue;
        table |= bit;
        winningNumbers[i++] = inputNum;
    }
    for(i=0;i<DATA_SIZE;++i)
        printf("%d ", winningNumbers[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 storing the entire table in a 64-bit unsigned. I was about to post a simple lookup table answer, but this is considerably more concise, exploiting the fact that input domain is fewer than 64 contiguous elements.

Comment: @BLUEPIXU it works amazing thank you. This is amazing can you please show me what you have done?? and how you made my code so much compressed

Comment: @Leoc He uses a 64bit number as a "table" Each number in your input is a value between 1 and 50. So he takes the number (already range-checked to be in between 1..50), and creates a 64bit value with a single bit lit, that bit being the one that corresponds to the input number. This is then bitwise-ANDed against the table var (a 64bit value initially set to `0`, i.e. all bits cleared). If the matching bit in the table var is already lit, the number has been seen before, otherwise we set it and move to the next number.

Comment: @WhozCraig ahh I see, that's pretty cool, but I want to be original is there any way my code can be fixed up. I dont want to offend anyone. Its beautiful piece of code but thats just how I am

Comment: Nothing stopping you from doing the same. Just nix most of the duplicate-detection logic out of your code and replace it with the table-var approach here. The rest of your code you can certainly keep and continue to work on as needed. This really is a reasonably elegant solution for your duplicate-detection woes, and should be considered.

Comment: If I kept continuing my code will I eventually hit the solution? I agree this is really reasonably but I want to finish what I have done. Is my way not efficient, cleaver, not well written?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DATA_SIZE 6

int inputNumberWithRangeCheck(const char *msg, const char *errMsg, int rangeStart, int rangeEnd){
    char inputLine[256];
    int n;

    for(;;){
        printf("%s", msg);
        fgets(inputLine, sizeof(inputLine), stdin);
        if(sscanf(inputLine, "%d", &n) != 1 || n < rangeStart || n > rangeEnd)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", errMsg);
        else
            return n;
    }
}

int inputNumber(void){
    return inputNumberWithRangeCheck(
        "\nPlease enter the winning ticket number!(#'s must be between 1-49): ",
        "Invalid Input.\n",
        1,49);
}

int *inputArray(int *array, size_t size){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        printf("\nInput for No.%d\n", i+1);
        array[i] = inputNumber();
    }
    return array;
}

int **duplicateCheck(int *array, size_t size){
    int **check, count;
    int i, j;

    check = malloc(size*sizeof(int*));
    if(!check){
        perror("memory allocate\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    //There is no need to sort the case of a small amount of data
    //(Cost of this loop because about bubble sort)
    for(count=i=0;i<size -1;++i){
        for(j=i+1;j<size;++j){
            if(array[i] == array[j]){
                check[count++] = &array[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    check[count] = NULL;
    if(count)
        return check;
    else {
        free(check);
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int winningNumbers[DATA_SIZE];
    int **duplication;
    int i, j;

    inputArray(winningNumbers, DATA_SIZE);

    while(NULL!=(duplication = duplicateCheck(winningNumbers, DATA_SIZE))){
        for(i=0;i<DATA_SIZE;++i){
            if(duplication[i]){
                printf("\nyour input numbers : ");
                for(j=0;j<DATA_SIZE;++j)
                    printf("%d ", winningNumbers[j]);
                fprintf(stderr, "\nThere is duplicate. Please re-enter.\n");
                *duplication[i] = inputNumber();
            } else
                break;
        }
        free(duplication);
    }
    for(i=0;i<DATA_SIZE;++i)
        printf("%d ", winningNumbers[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then what's the difference

Comment: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
  ...*msg, char *errMsg, int rangeStart, int rangeEnd)

warning: format string is not a string literal
      (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]

ormat string is not a string literal
      (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]

Comment: @Leoc warning will appear in `clang`, but it is not the error. It is assumed that have failed to copy the code if error is that out.

Comment: I was fixed `inputNumberWithRangeCheck`. I think the warning will become not now.